# What is the difference between a function and getter in Dart?

Tags: function, dart, getter

To get a value from a function I can to this:

```
bool goOutside() {
    if(today is a good day){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But I can also do this:

```
bool get goOutside {
    if(today is a good day){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Can someone tell me the difference between those? Which one is the *'right'* one or for what use cases are they are good?

Comment: what you cant do is `bool get goOutside(myParams)`, in sort where i dont need parameters I can use getter, else function

Comment: If there are no arguments, then it depends on how you want the callsites to look.  Do you want them to look like function calls or like accessing variables?  If there are side-effects, prefer making it look like a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for invoking the code is different. In the case of the `get` you would just use `print(goOutside);` but in the case of the function you would call with the `()` operator as in `print(goOutside());`. This also means the function can accept parameters in the arguments list but the getter cannot.

I would go for a getter instead of a function that accepts no parameters as this could result in cleaner and more maintainable code. However if the code has any funny business such as IO or program-visible side-effects I would go for the function to make this clear and avoid hard to find bugs.

**Disclaimer:* I am not a Dart expert. This answer is speculative.*

Comment: The [official advice on when to use a getter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-use-getters-for-operations-that-conceptually-access-properties) gives similar reasons to this answer.